# YUI3 io-upload-iframe

Tags: javascript, file-upload, io, yui3, asyncfileupload

Can you use yui3's io-upload-iframe to send form data along with the file upload?  I am setting the form's id, like I normally would to serialize the form data, but since I am setting `upload : true`, it doesn't seem to pass any form data with the request.  Here is the code I am using.

```
var cfg = {
    method: 'POST',
    form: {
        id: Y.ong('#myform'),
        upload: true
    }
};
var request = Y.io(requestURL, cfg);
```

Comment: Does it really work? I guess you should write Y.one, not Y.ong